# Show data of a JSON array with a alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

I want to show data of a JSON array, I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
var Content = [{
    "01":[{"text":"blablablablabla","foo":"abeille :o"}],
    "02":[{"text":"blobloblobloblo","fuuu":"bzzzz :)"}],
    "03":[{"text":"blibliblibli","fiii":"bzzoooo ;)"}]
}];
alert(Content.01.foo);
```

How to do this?

Comment: This is actually a series of Javascript literals, not JSON.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need quotes and  array indices.

```
   //   v---index 0 of the Array
Content[0]["01"][0].foo
   //            ^---index 0 of the Array
   //     ^----^---square brackets and quotes
```

Comment: To be clear, what's happening here is that every [] is an array (though in this case each one only has one element).

Answer (score 4):

`Content` is an array containing an object, not an object.

Identifiers cannot start with a number, so you cannot use them to access a property that starts with a number. You have to use square bracket notation (which is based on strings) instead of the identifier based dot notation.

Each numeric property in your object contains an array containing an object, not an object.

```
alert(Content[0]['01'][0].foo)
```

Comment: @RochesterFox, really? http://jsfiddle.net/FxzTF/

Comment: @RochesterFox — Works for me: http://jsbin.com/awikop/1/

Answer (score 0):

You used useless `[]`

object - {}
array  - []

For more details about sintax JSON please take a look **[here](http://www.json.org/)**

Modify your code in this way

```
var Content = {
    "01":{"text":"blablablablabla","foo":"abeille :o"},
    "02":{"text":"blobloblobloblo","fuuu":"bzzzz :)"},
    "03":{"text":"blibliblibli","fiii":"bzzoooo ;)"}
};
alert(Content['01'].foo);
```